# How to make $user object work on other pages if the user is logged in and the login page redirects to user profile

Tags: php, session, session-variables

Inside index.php page is some login code, and when the user logs in it redirects them to the index.php page (it simply refreshes the index page) and viola, the user is logged in successfully.

However when I change the redirect to another page (logged_in.php), my $user object doesn't seem to have any data available to check if the user is logged in or not. I presume the $user object's data is not being transferred from index.php session to logged_in.php session vars.

The following code works for the index.php redirect:

```
require_once 'core/init.php';

session_start();

$user = $_SESSION["user"];

    if (!$user->isLoggedIn())   
{   
    echo 'not logged in';
    //Redirect::to('index.php');
}
if ($user->isLoggedIn()) 
{
    echo escape($user->data()->name);
}
```

But the same code doesn't work for logged_in.php.

The error that php displays:

```
Undefined variable: _SESSION in C:\wamp\etc...
```

It's something simple like session handling I'm sure.

Here's the login code:

```
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['login'])) 
    {
        //echo "teste";
        if(Token::check(Input::get('token'))) 
        {   
            //echo "testeasd";
            $validate = new Validate();
            $validation = $validate->check($_POST, array(
              'username' => array('required' => true),
              'password' => array('required' => true)
            ));
            if($validation->passed()) 
            {
                //echo "Passou!";
                $user = new User();
                $remember = (Input::get('remember') === 'on') ? true : false;
                $login = $user->login(Input::get('username'), Input::get('password'), $remember);
                if($login) 
                {
                    $_SESSION["user"] = $user;
                    //echo $_SESSION['user'];
                    //print_r($_SESSION['user']);
                    Redirect::to('logged_in.php');
                } 
                else 
                {
                    echo "<p class='label label-danger'>Sorry, logging in failed.</p><br><br>";
                }

            } 
            else 
            {
                foreach($validation->errors() as $error) 
                {
                    echo $error, '<br>';
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and logged_in.php simply contains the code like index.php does:

```
require_once 'core/init.php';

session_start();

$user = $_SESSION["user"];

    if (!$user->isLoggedIn())   
{   
    echo 'not logged in';
    //Redirect::to('index.php');
}
if ($user->isLoggedIn()) 
{
    echo escape($user->data()->name);
}
```

Something to note:

In index.php I have a require_once 'init.php' that intialises classes and functions including user, validate, cookie, config, db, input, hash and other such things. index.php also has `$user = new User();` code at the top.

Go easy on me -I'm a newb just trying to understand simple logins.

Comment: if you have two different file then you should have to start_session for both file

Comment: I did try that to no avail. I'll add it in to my question though thanks.

Comment: The only reason you're getting the error:  

Undefined variable: _SESSION in C:\wamp\etc...

is if you forget the dollar ($" in front:  $_SESSION.

Where does this error really came from?  For sure it does't seem to be coming from the logged_in.php.

Comment: My guess is that when php reads logged_in.php it reads the `$user = $_SESSION["user"];` part and throws the error. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I got rid of the error but now I have another error: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function isLoggedIn() on string in C:\wamp642\www\social_app\logged_in.php`. Also, when I echo the `$_SESSION['user']` it displays the 'row_id' of the user from the database. I'm sure that 'core/init.php' initialises sessions and cookies, but I'm having trouble getting the $user object to go from index.php to logged_in.php. Is there a way to echo all session variables?

Answer (score 0):

You need to start session in every script where you need access to $_SESSION variable but instead of putting session_start(); in every single script you can create a file headers.php and put there all your repetitive code including session_start();

```
session_start(); // add this line

$user = $_SESSION["user"];

    if (!$user->isLoggedIn())   
{   
    echo 'not logged in';
    //Redirect::to('index.php');
}
if ($user->isLoggedIn()) 
{
    echo escape($user->data()->name);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it hasn't worked yet. I added `require_once 'core/init.php';` to my logged_in.php too so it has the same included classes and functions as the index.php page. Still not working.

Comment: Ok..instead adding init file have you tried with adding session_start on top of the page?

Comment: Yea. It still throws the same error. `require_once 'core/init.php';` has a session_start() in it anyway. I've tried with and without session_start at the top of each page, and with and without `require_once 'core/init.php';`.

Comment: Asking again.  Exactly where does the error came from?  Usually PHP will tell you.  Have that info or none?

Comment: Oh sorry I see what you mean. Yea it comes form logged_in.php line 27: `if (!$user->isLoggedIn()) {` I managed to get rid of the error by adding `require_once 'core/init.php';` to logged_in.php. Should I add that code?

Comment: I just tried to see if other $user data could be echo'd and it can. `escape($user->data()->username);` and `escape($user->data()->name);` are echo'ing the correct items in logged_in.php.

Comment: Can't seem to replicate your error.  Everything's working fine with your code on my end.  Could be something else we're not seeing there.

By the way, you don't need to verify "isLoggedIn()" twice.  Just branch it with the else:

if (!$user->isLoggedIn())
{
    echo 'not logged in';
} else {
    echo escape($user->data()->name);
}

Comment: Sorted. I had to add `$user = new User();` and `require_once 'core/init.php';` for it to work.